# pandas: fill a column by applying a class method to another column (which contains classes)

Tags: python, pandas, class

i have a pandas dataframe where one of the column is filled with class objects, like the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
class rec:
    def test(self, a):
        return a
class rec1:
    def test(self, a):
        return a*3
x= rec()
y = rec1()
list = [x,y]
df=pd.DataFrame(list, columns=['first'])
df['second']=['a1','b1']

print(df)
                                          first second
0   <__main__.rec object at 0x000000180AAE9208>     a1
1  <__main__.rec1 object at 0x000000180AACBEB8>     b1
```

now, i wish to create a new column by applying the method "test" to column 'first', by reading input for "test" from column 'second'.
this loop works:

```
df['third']=0
for i in (0,1):
 df['third'][i] = df['first'][i].test(df['second'][i])
```

but i wonder if i can avoid the loop and use something more similar to the following code (which does not work):

```
df['third'] = df['first'].test(df['second'])
```

any advice? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't that hard to do actually. You can use `np.vectorize`.

```
f = lambda x, y: x.test(y)
v = np.vectorize(f)

df['third'] = v(df['first'], df['second'])

df    
                                   first second   third
0   <__main__.rec object at 0x1038b1ef0>     a1      a1
1  <__main__.rec1 object at 0x1038b1c18>     b1  b1b1b1
```

Comment: thank you. that seems ok. even though numpy manual says vectorize is provided for convenience not for performace and implementation is essentially a for loop.

Comment: @ste976 I wasn’t using it for performance, this is the most concise way I can think to solve your problem. Don’t forget to accept the answer if it works. Thanks.